# Using aggregate in a dataframe with NA without dropping rows

Tags: r, aggregate

I am using aggregate to get the means of several variables by a specific category (cy), but there are a few NA's in my dataframe.  I am using aggregate rather than ddply because from my understanding it takes care of NA's similarly to using rm.na=TRUE.  The problem is that it drops all rows containing NA in the output, so the means are slightly off.

Dataframe:

`>      bt     cy   cl   pf  ne       YH    YI
1        1      H   1    95 70.0      20    20
2        2      H   1    25 70.0      46    50
3        1      H   1     0 70.0      40    45
4        2      H   1    95 59.9      40    40
5        2      H   1    75 59.9      36    57
6        2      H   1     5 70.0      35    43
7        1      H   1    50 59.9      20    36
8        2      H   1    95 59.9      40    42
9        3      H   1    95 49.5      17    48
10       2      H   1     5 70.0      42    42
11       2      H   1    95 49.5      19    30
12       3      H   1    25 49.5      33    51
13       1      H   1    75 49.5       5    26
14       1      H   1     5 70.0      35    37
15       1      H   1     5 59.9      20    40
16       2      H   1    95 49.5      29    53
17       2      H   1    75 70.0      41    41
18       2      H   1     0 70.0      10    10
19       2      H   1    95 49.5      25    32
20       1      H   1    95 59.9      10    11
21       2      H   1     0 29.5      20    28
22       1      H   1    95 29.5      11    27
23       2      H   1    25 59.9      26    26
24       1      H   1     5 70.0      30    30
25       3      H   1    25 29.5      20    30
26       3      H   1    50 70.0       5     5
27       1      H   1     0 59.9       3    10
28       1      K   1     5 49.5      25    29
29       2      K   1     0 49.5      30    32
30       1      K   1    95 49.5      13    24
31       1      K   1     0 39.5      13    13
32       2      M   1    NA 70.0      45    50
33       3      M   1    25 59.9       3    34'`

The full dataframe has 74 rows, and there are NA's peppered throughout all but two columns (cy and cl).

My code looks like this:
`meancnty<-(aggregate(cbind(pf,ne,YH,YI)~cy, data = newChart, FUN=mean))`

I double checked in excel, and the means this function produces are for a dataset of N=69, after removing all rows containing NA's.  Is there any way to tell R to ignore the NA's rather than remove the rows, other than taking the mean of each variable by county (I have a lot of variables to summarize by many different categories)?

Thank you

Comment: If your problem is with `NA` values, you should probably include a sample of data with some `NA` values in it...

Comment: @Gregor - I just added the whole dataframe with all the NA's

Comment: `aggregate(cbind(pf,ne,YH,YI)~cy, data = newChart, FUN=mean, na.rm=TRUE, na.action=na.pass)` - You can remove `NA`s in the mean calculation using the `na.rm=TRUE` argument, while `na.action=na.pass` means that the `NA` values are not deleted prior to the function being run. `na.action=na.omit` is the default for the `aggregate` formula interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using `dplyr`

```
df %>%
  group_by(cy) %>%
  summarize_all(mean, na.rm = TRUE)

#      cy       bt        cl       pf       ne       YH       YI
# 1     H 1.785714 0.7209302 53.41463 51.75952 21.92857 29.40476
# 2     K 1.333333 0.8333333 33.33333 47.83333 20.66667 27.33333
# 3     M 1.777778 0.4444444 63.75000 58.68889 24.88889 44.22222
# 4     O 2.062500 0.8750000 31.66667 53.05333 18.06667 30.78571
```

Comment: it worked!  You have rescued me from hours of banging my head against the desk - thank you!

Answer (score -1):

I think this will work:

```
meancnty<-(aggregate(with(newChart(cbind(pf,ne,YH,YI), 
           by = list(newchart$cy), FUN=mean, na.rm=T))
```

I used the following test data:

```
> q<- data.frame(y = sample(c(0,1), 10, replace=T), a = runif(10, 1, 100), b=runif(10, 20,30))
> q$a[c(2, 5, 7)]<- NA
> q$b[c(1, 3, 4)]<- NA
> q
   y        a        b
1  0 86.87961       NA
2  0       NA 22.39432
3  0 89.38810       NA
4  0 12.96266       NA
5  1       NA 22.07757
6  0 73.96121 24.13154
7  0       NA 22.31431
8  1 62.77095 21.46395
9  0 55.28476 23.14393
10 0 14.01912 28.08305
```

Using your code from above, I get:

```
> aggregate(cbind(a,b)~y, data=q, mean, na.rm=T)
  y        a        b
1 0 47.75503 25.11951
2 1 62.77095 21.46395
```

which is wrong, i.e. it deletes all rows with any `NAs` and then takes the mean.
This however gave the right result:

```
> aggregate(with(q, cbind(a, b)), by = list(q$y), mean, na.rm=T)
  Group.1        a        b
1       0 55.41591 24.01343
2       1 62.77095 21.77076
```

It did `na.rm=T` by column first, and then took the average by group.

Unfortunately, I have no idea why that is, but my guess is that is has to do with the class of `y`.

Comment: Thanks, @Yannis Vassiliadis!  This one works as well.  I wonder if it's the list function that keeps the rows from being dropped.

Comment: @Anthony - the standard version of `aggregate` not using formulas doesn't have an `na.action=na.omit` by default. It has nothing to do with the `list()` usage. The whole thing could be simplified too - `aggregate(q[c("a","b")], q["y"], mean, na.rm=TRUE)` for instance as selecting like `q[c("var")]` will retain `data.frame/list` objects.